# Не работает BroadcastRecivier в фоне

Tags: java, android, activity, broadcast-receiver, context

Есть широковещательный приёмник, который запускает активность locky при включении экрана. Но проблема в том, что этот код работает только когда приложение включено(или скрыто, но не закрыто). Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытом всё тоже работало? Вот код ресивера:

```
public class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(P.TAG, "ScreenService onReceive");

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        Intent go_locky = new Intent(context, locky.class);
    context.startActivity(go_locky);
    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
        //и отключение экрана
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используйте Android 10, то это невозможно. На Android 10 Google запретила открытие Activity, пока приложение свернуто.

Comment: Да при свернутом работает. Вот Learn English on Lockscreen как-то все это осуществляет...

Comment: Быть может можно не активити, а Alert Dialog хотя бы

Comment: Рекомендуемый кейс вызова Activity на Android 10, это создать уведомление, и по клике по нему, перейти в приложение.